# Cross website servlet to servlet communication framework

Tags: java, servlets, rpc

I did a lot of research on this but couldn't find a concrete answer. I want to write an application framework which defines server side interfaces which other people can implement and deploy on their servers in the form of small servlets. I want a way to be able to do an RPC on these methods without having the hassle of dealing with packing and unpacking parameters in the request and response myself. I am sure a decent framework must exist for such a thing but I just cannot pinpoint the right one.

I'd appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: What do you want?  Java-only?  Parameters are full objects and not just strings?  Standards based?  Tiny?

Comment: Full object support would be nice but not a must have. Having a string parameter alone can be useful since I can then pass well formatted JSON/XML around. I want easy integration with servlets. Don't care about size that much but has to be fast with as little setup as possible. I am willing to add more functionality to it if I get something basic

Answer (score 2):

How about Java REST standard JAX-RS? There are multiple implementations: [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/), [RESTeasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy), etc..

They serialize/deserialize objects automatically. REST is standard so client implementations exist for any language/platform.

Comment: That's not quite RPC. I want something like the GWT RPC or possibly more like the Gadgets framework for the waveprotocol.

Comment: Most REST implementations serialize/deserialize objects automatically so they get close to RPC. Not true RPC but close.